# What is the import/export tariff cost from Poland to USA and from USA to Poland?

Tags: air-travel, usa, regulations, poland, import-taxes

I plan on buying shoes and clothes with the intention of transporting them to USA. I am wondering how much tax I will have to pay to transfer these products? If my shoes are not in the boxes and clothes are without tags, will I still have to pay the tariff?

I also plan on transporting a lot of clothes and shoes from USA to Poland so I also wish to know, what are the tariffs for products entering Poland?

In addition to this, what fees might I expect regarding other products such as; appliances, jewellery and beauty products?

Comment: This question is not really on topic, but you can look up US tariff rates at http://hts.usitc.gov/ .

Comment: I'm reopening this as on-topic. As long as it's for personal use, customs rates are an on-topic area for Travel.SE. This is because in many jurisdictions, you may be surprised to find that you have to pay duty even for personal items if they fall outside certain quantity limits or circumstances. So this is not a 'business-only' situation.

Comment: this is not for business just that we are buying a lot of things

Answer (score 2):

Bringing goods from Poland to the US has a customs duty exemption of $800, assuming you're overseas for longer than 48 hours.  This applies to all goods.

[Source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/363/kw/personal%20use)

[More (far too many) details](http://www.cbp.gov/linkhandler/cgov/travel/vacation/kbyg/kbyg_regulations.ctt/kbyg_regulations.pdf)

For the US to Poland the exemption is EUR 300 (crossing the border by land) or EUR 430 (crossing by air or sea).

[Source](http://www.mf.gov.pl/_files_/sluzba_celna/euro2012/ulotki/leaflet_pl+uk_eng2.pdf)

If your goods exceeds these totals, the duty depends on the type of good, the amount of goods, etc.  If you significantly exceed those limitations above, I'd suggest contacting the appropriate authorities for more information.

If you wear the clothes and don't indicate they are new, you will probably be able to avoid any tariffs but if you are caught it will probably result in a very significant fine and potential jail time.

Comment: ok so I read a lot from the booklet but I am still confused is the tariff 3% after the $800 limit for shoes??